# video not playing in YoutubePlayer

Tags: android, youtubeplayer

I have a `youtubePlayer` instance com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
. when I try to start this video by the mobile network I got the error
`VIDEO_NOT_PLAYABLE_IN_EMBEDDED_PLAYER`

Here's the code:

```
         youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                String videoId =YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE;
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId,0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what you are passing in the `youtubePlayer.loadVideo`

`String videoId =YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE;` is not a valid video `URL`.